# SendGrid email service in Blazor - Dependency Injection or Static method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, sendgrid, blazor-server-side

I am setting up a SendGrid email sender in a Blazor app (.NET 5).

Per the SendGrid docs and examples, they are writing a method signed as `static async Task` and then they `await` the response from their api. Their example code just runs immediately from `Main()` and doesn't show any method calls.

Does using this as a static method violate how I should be using Dependency Injenction? Shouldn't I register this EmailSender class as a service with Dependency Injection and then inject it in my components that need to send emails?

Code from SendGrid example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Execute().Wait();
}

static async Task Execute()
{
    //Boilerplate code setting up email from/to/apiKey etc removed
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

With this setup, I could make the Execute() method public and then call it directly as a static method.

Would it be more appropriate to make something like the following:

```
public class EmailService
{
    public async Task SendEmail(string to, string subject, string message)
    {
        //Boilerplate code setting up email from/to/apiKey etc removed
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Then I could inject and use the service via DI, like:

```
@inject EmailService emailService

@code {
    //Calling line below in the appropriate spot
    await emailService.SendEmail(to, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of nuget packages to send mails while the framework has everything to do it.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Understood there are things built in that can do so, but the decision was made to use SendGrid for other features they offer.

Comment: @aterbo thanks, I understand now! I just bring an opinion from the code I see. Sorry for my suggestion.

Comment: No need to apologize, I appreciate the input

Comment: You would appear to be on the right lines.   However, question : What's `client` in `var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);`?  It must be defined somewhere in the SendGrid example.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis `client` is something from the SendGrid api. Sorry, it'd defined in the boilerplate code that I removed, but I left it in just because it's the final `await`ed call that actually sends the email. Which approach do you think is the right lines--Calling via static method, or registering it in the DI system?

Comment: In general you should be looking to separate your UI code from your data and application specific code.  Using DI services to represent your application/data access code is good.  If your interested look up `Clean Design` - I have a short article here about it - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Design/Clean-Design-In-Blazor.html

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I understand the reasons for using the DI system for structuring code. My question is more around why the library would use a Static example, and if it's more "appropriate" to refactor this into the DI system.

Comment: [Polite]  ????   Why come back after 10 months, and this is a comment not an answer.  If you have a current question raise a new issue.

Comment: Sorry, someone just upvoted this question again out of nowhere, so it popped up in my inbox and I circled back to it.

Answer (score 4):

A generalized implementation in .NET Core:

Startup.cs

```
using SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // sendgrid
        services.AddSendGrid(options =>
        {
            options.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
        });
    }
}
```

EmailController.cs

```
using SendGrid; // nuget package

public class EmailController : ControllerBase
{
    private ISendGridClient _sendGridClient;
    
    public EmailController(ISendGridClient sendGridClient)
    {
        _sendGridClient = sendGridClient;
    }
    
    public IActionResult SendEmail(Email email)
    {
        var emailManager = new EmailManager(_sendGridClient);
        return emailManager.SendEmail(email);
    }
}
```

EmailManager.cs

```
using SendGrid;

public class EmailManager
{
    private ISendGridClient _sendGridClient;
    
    public EmailManager(ISendGridClient sendGridClient)
    {
        _sendGridClient = sendGridClient;
    }
    
    public bool SendEmail(Email email)
    {
        ...
        var response = await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, the implementation that I have is working properly. My question is specifically around why SendGrid would show examples using static methods over the DI system, and if it's more appropriate to use the DI system in a Blazor application.

Answer (score 0):

**An example for NET 6 Web API with Controllers**

https://github.com/Davidmendoza1987/dotnet-sendgrid-examples

You will need the following nuget packages installed

- SendGrid
- SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Program.cs

```
using SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Custom Code
builder.Services.AddThirdPartyServices();
builder.Services.AddRepositories();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();    
app.UseAuthorization();    
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Repositories;

namespace SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Extensions;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddThirdPartyServices(this IServiceCollection servicesCollection)
    {
        var sendGridApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
        if (sendGridApiKey is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(sendGridApiKey, "SendGrid API key has not been configured"); 
        }

        servicesCollection.AddSendGrid(options => options.ApiKey = sendGridApiKey);

        return servicesCollection;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddRepositories(this IServiceCollection servicesCollection)
    {
        servicesCollection.AddTransient<ISendGridRepository, SendGridRepository>(x =>
            new SendGridRepository(x.GetRequiredService<ISendGridClient>()));

        return servicesCollection;
    }    
}
```

SendEmailRequest.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Models;

public class SendEmailRequest
{
    [Required]
    public List<string> To { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    [Required]
    public string From { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public string FromName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? PlainTextContent { get; set; }

    public string? HtmlContent { get; set; }

    public bool? ShowAllRecipients { get; set; } = false;
}
```

SendGridController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using SendGrid;
using SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Models;
using SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Repositories;

namespace SendGridExample.Net6.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SendGridController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISendGridRepository sendGridRepository;

    public SendGridController(ISendGridRepository sendGridRepository) => this.sendGridRepository = sendGridRepository;

    [HttpPost("send-email")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Response), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> SendEmail([FromBody, BindRequired] SendEmailRequest request)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.PlainTextContent) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.HtmlContent))
        {
            return BadRequest("Either PlainTextContent or HtmlContent must be provided.");
        }

        var response = await sendGridRepository.SendTransactionEmailAsync(request);
        return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, response);
    }
}
```

SendGridRepository.cs

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Models;

namespace SendGridExample.Net6.V1.Repositories;

public interface ISendGridRepository
{
    Task<Response> SendTransactionEmailAsync(SendEmailRequest request);
}

public class SendGridRepository : ISendGridRepository
{
    private readonly ISendGridClient sendGridClient;

    public SendGridRepository(ISendGridClient sendGridClient) => this.sendGridClient = sendGridClient;

    public async Task<Response> SendTransactionEmailAsync(SendEmailRequest request)
    {
        var toAddresses = request.To.Select(n => new EmailAddress(n)).ToList();
        var fromAddress = new EmailAddress(request.From, request.FromName);
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(fromAddress, toAddresses, request.Subject, request.PlainTextContent, request.HtmlContent, request.ShowAllRecipients!.Value);

        return await sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```